# Create a raster dataset containing the number of returns from a las file?

Tags: raster, lidar, classification, rasterization, las

I already created DEMs, DTMs, DSMs from a LiDAR (LAS) file with a little help from the internet. However, right now I'm kind of stuck in my research.

I want to create a raster file which contains for each pixel the number of returns from the las file. So that the result would be a raster file with 5 classes (values) because the LiDAR system used to generate the data was able to differentiate in up to 5 LiDAR returns from one pulse.

ArcGIS 10.2.2, ERDAS Imagine 2014 and LAStools are available to do that job.